# How to navigate with history.push in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Can I add my component name in: 
eg : `this.props.history.push(<Sample/>)`

I have an idea about adding the path in this: `this.props.history.push("/Sample")`.

Or how can I navigate it to my component:

```
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("error", error);
    this.setState({
        finishedStep: false,
    });
    this.props.history.push("<Sample/>");
});
```

If the finished step is `false`, I want to navigate it to my `<Sample>` component.

Comment: You need to create a `<Route path="/sample">` component with the path you need, then using the `history.push('Sample')` call in your component if you want to redirect. See one example here: [Basic Routing](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing)

Comment: Can you plz give me an example

Comment: You must have a route configured against Sample component, to be able to navigate to sample component you should do something like this `this.props.history.push('/sample')`

Comment: Have you used React-router in your App. If so how have your configured your routes

Comment: so when i've done the routing configured, and trying to pass this.props.history.push('/sample'). The UI page is getting distorted. Is there any other way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already configured the corresponding route for the `<Sample />` Component.

Wrap your component with `react-router-dom`

Install - react-router-dom

`npm install --save react-router-dom`

Example:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
   handleSubmit = (user) => {
     saveUser(user).then(() =>
     this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
     )).catch((error) => {
      console.log("error", error);
      this.setState({
        finishedStep: false,
      });
      this.props.history.push("/Sample");
     })
   }      
   render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(YourComponent)
```

Another approach that you could take without using `react-router-dom` is.

```
render() {
    if (this.state.finishedStep === false) {
      return <Redirect to='/Sample' />
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: This particular piece of code is working , but my <Sample> component is a part of a wizard, so when i have configure it in route and writing this.props.history.push("/Sample");. It is navigating to Sample, but distorting its UI

Comment: `history.push()` api takes a location parameter, For the history api to work correctly, this location should be configured inside your `routes.js`.  From what it looks like you've not configured `/sample` inside your routes.js.  Add `<Route path="/sample" component={<Sample />} />` inside your routes.js for it to work correctly

Comment: i have done that and navigation is working but the ui of the page is distorted.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by distortion, is some other component getting rendered instead of the Sample component ? or is the CSS getting messed up ? Can you show how you've configured the routes, and probably an image of what you're seeing as distortion.

Comment: If your <Sample> Component is part of the <Wizard> component, It's highly possible that  the wizard component is passing some props to the Sample component for it to get rendered correctly. It could be that while rendering the <Sample> component independently, the props are undefined and thus you see the distortion.

Comment: {
    component: Sample,
    path: "/sample",
    exact: true,
    title: "Sample",
  },actually this sample component is a part of wizard, so the css is getting messed up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213676/discussion-between-singh-and-nitte93user3232918).

Comment: here's the thing, 
Assuming that the sample component is dependent upon the props passed by the wizard. If you want to render only the Sample component upon redirection, then you need to make sure that all the props are passed to it independently as well.